# ArgumentError: Error #2005: Parameter 0 is of the incorrect type. Should be type Filter

Tags: apache-flex, filter, actionscript, flex-spark

And my code is really simple:

```
date = new StyleableTextField();
date.filters = [new DropShadowFilter(1,90,0xffffff)];
```

What is wrong? This is crazy

Ok, I think this need more information: 
I am doing this in an item renderer (extends LabelItemRenderer). The method is override protected function createChildren():void

Maybe I have to call set filters later?

Comment: import flash.filters.DropShadowFilter;

instead of

import spark.filters.DropShadowFilter;

This solved it

Answer (score 1):

ropo is right

This happend with me also.

I first have applied the GlowFilter to the UIComponent which requires spark.filters.GlowFilter

Then I changed the code and applied to Sprite which requires flash.filters.GlowFilter

Since GlowFilter was already imported, the FlashBuilder did not throw any compile error but it throwed the error in the run-time.

So just make sure if applying filters to Flex component then import

```
  spark.filters.*
```

and for the non-flex

```
  flash.filters.*
```

Also, just in case if somene wants to apply filters to both flex and flash components use fully qualified name

```
  flexComp.filters = [new spark.filters.DropShadowFilter(1,90,0xffffff)];
  flashComp.filters = [new flash.filters.DropShadowFilter(1,90,0xffffff)];
```